# Presubmit doesn't fire?

Tags: html, node.js, polymer, iron-form

I have an iron-form element and I'm trying to attach a file to the POST request. However, `iron-form-presubmit` never fires. I have the following function defined:

```
  restForm.addEventListener('iron-form-presubmit', function() {
    console.log('restForm.addEventListener presubmit')
    this.request.method = 'post';
    this.request.params = uploadComponentId.files[0];
    this.request.body = self.buildFormDataObject(this.request.body);
    restForm.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = 'Processing Request';
  });
```

But I never see `'restForm.addEventListener presubmit'` on the console (Chrome dev tools), although I do see every other log, so I guess the function never gets called. When should the `iron-form-presubmit` event fire?

The form itself:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" is="iron-form" method="post" action="http://localhost:7733/receivedoc" id="restForm" >
        <px-file-upload 
          id="uploadComponentId"
          message="Drag and drop files here, or click the button below." 
          multiple=false 
          accept=".xls,.xlsx">
        </px-file-upload>
        <button class="btn btn--large btn--icon" id="saveDataSetButton">
          <i class="fa-briefcase">Generate Pacing File</i>
        </button>
      </form>
```

Comment: I might be missing something pretty obvious here.. but to have the events from `iron-form` shouldn't you use the `iron-form` element instead of the HTML `form` element?

Comment: or maybe to have it wrap the `form` element, not instead of it, in fact.. as you can see in the docs: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-form